# Return a firebase database reference as an array in a cloud function

Tags: angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Below is the firebase database reference returned as an array in my AngularJS scope:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users").child(user.uid).child("week1");
$firebaseArray(ref);
```

However when I tried writing the same code in my `index.js` file for a database Cloud Function, there was an error message:

> ReferenceError: $firebaseArray is not defined at /user_code/index.js:22:18

Is there a way to make a Firebase reference ref return as an array in my `index.js` Cloud Functions file since `$firebaseArray` is not defined outside the AngularJS scope?

Below is an illustration of the database:

```
 users: {
   user uid (generated by push) : {
       deviceToken : "tokenID",
       name : "Display Name"
   },
   anotherUserID : {
       deviceToken : "tokenID",
       name : "Display Name"
   },
Players: {
    player1: John,
    Player2: ken,
}
```

Is there a way for a change in the `Players` database node to trigger a function in the `users` node (for each user):

```
exports.update = functions.database.ref('/Player')
    .onWrite(event=>{
      console.log(event.data);
      var ref = admin.database().ref('/users/'+ user.uid+ '/week1');
      ref.set(10);
      return;
    });
```

My issue was accessing the `user.uid` (created by the `push()` method) for each user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cloud Functions, you can use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin) to save and retrieve data from the database. To initialize the Admin SDK, you can use [environment configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env#use_environment_configuration_to_initialize_a_module):

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

You can then attach a [value listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#value) to your database reference, utilizing and returning a [JavaScript Promise](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions#how_promises_work_with_functions) to keep the function alive and chain your logic:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref("/users").child(user.uid).child("week1");

return ref.once("value").then(snapshot => {
    const values = snapshot.val();

    // Do something with the snapshot
});
```

The `values` variable here will be assigned an array of the values at the location (see [`val()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot#val)), so could be used in place of `$firebaseArray`.

---

If you need to obtain a reference to the node that triggered your database function, you can use the [`event`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events#handle_event_data) parameter from the function definition:

```
let ref = event.data.ref;
```

This is useful if you need to obtain the specific location in the database that triggered your function. The [`event.data`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Event#data) variable is a [`DeltaSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) instance for database functions.

Similarly, you can use `event.params` to obtain any of the variables specified in a database trigger definition, for example `{uid}` in the below definition can be obtain using `event.params.uid`:

```
exports.example = functions.database.ref('/users/{uid}')
    .onWrite(event => {
      const uid = event.params.uid;
      // ...
    });
```

The method you take here depends on what work you need your function to perform, how it's triggered and what variables or values you need access to.

Remember that your function can freely read and write data anywhere in the database using the Admin SDK too.

---

In your newest example, it would be hard to match a node at `/players` to `/users` because there isn't a value with the user's UID. So you would need to change the `/players` child nodes to include further data, something like:

```
players : {
    player1 : {
        name: "John",
        uid: "anotherUserID"
    }
}
```

You could then extract this `uid` using `event.data.child('uid').val()` from your function (where your function is triggered by children under this node using `/players/{playerId}`):

```
exports.update = functions.database.ref('/players/{playerId}')
    .onWrite(event=>{
      console.log(event.data);
      const uid = event.data.child('uid').val();
      var ref = admin.database().ref('/users/' + uid + '/week1');
      ref.set(10);
      return;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Another issue has come up though: Outside the Angular JS scope, 'user.uid'  returns an error message: " Error:  Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path: "/users/{user.uid}/week1". Paths must be non-empty strings ".

Comment: Each user has a unique ID created by push(). And it is important that I be able to access each user uid so that the function can run for each user in the cloud function. I there a way to access each user uid in the index.js file or can this only be done in the aungular js scope.

Comment: Is Angular `auth.uid` available in Cloud Functions already? If not, you may have to pass it through to your function. Depending on how it's triggered, you can pass [parameters to HTTP functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#read_values_from_the_request) or include it in the data with database triggers.

Comment: I dont beilieve it is available. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "include it in the data with databasse triggers". Sorry if that question is silly I'm quite new to firebase. My cloud function is triggered by changes to a database node.

Comment: Ok no problem, I meant you'll likely need to include it as a value on the node that triggers the function, or extract it from the `event` reference if it's part of the structure. I've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Wow Thanks so Much! So using your example is there a way I can trigger the function with a write to one database reference that will run a function in another database reference. I have edited the question to show an example.

Comment: With your current database structure, it's hard to match a node at `/players` to `/users` unless you changed the structure of the `/players` child nodes. I've added another example to my answer to further explain this. If this has helped, please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234). If you have any further questions, it might be worthwhile posting them separately to attract further interest and answers. I'll be happy to help where I can though.

Comment: thanks a bunch. I have added the uid structure to the /Players node as you asked . Final question, can I leave the trigger as /players but then still have the database ref for the uid as  admin.database.ref('/players/{playerId}/uid').val(); or must the wildcard be in the trigger? thanks

Comment: Ok great. The wildcard will need to be in the trigger to obtain it from `event.params`, but you could take it from `event.data.ref` or similar instead, depending on what node triggers the function. You may also be able to iterate through the child nodes using `event.data.forEach` as `event.data` will be a [`DeltaSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.DeltaSnapshot) instance of data at the triggering location, if that makes sense.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159501/discussion-between-deji-james-and-grimthorr).